# JS function won't return a return

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying in Redux change state via action but when I try to fire up the action it won't return anything. I think there is SOME problem in return statement but not sure how it is. Everything before return works. If I put there any console.log it returns but if I put console.log after return it won't return anything.

I am calling `setDir` through `mapDispatchProps`.

I have try to look at some cases but can't find answer anywhere.

Action.js

```
export const setDir = (dir) => {
  const newDirection = dir === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";
  return function (dispatch) {

    console.log(newDirection);
    dispatch({ type: SET_DIR, payload: newDirection });
  };
};
```

index.js

```
 const sortTable = (column) => {
  setColmn("val");
  setDir("desc");
  };
```

```
 <View style={styles.tableHeader}>
          {columns.map((column, index) => {
            {
              return (
                <TouchableOpacity
                  key={index}
                  style={styles.columnHeader}
                  onPress={() => sortTable(column)}
                >
                  <Text style={styles.columnHeaderTxt}>
                    {column + " "}
                    {selectedColumn === column && (
                      <AntDesign
                        size={20}
                        name={direction === "desc" ? "arrowdown" : "arrowup"}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
              );
            }
          })}
        </View>
```

```
const mapDispatchProps = (dispatch) =>
  bindActionCreators({ fetchVoziky, setColmn, setDir }, dispatch);
```

Comment: How exactly are you using `setDir`? Please include the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @FelixKling sorry. Now its updated

Comment: It doesn't look like you are "calling `setDir` through `mapDispatchProps`". You are calling it in `sortTable`. It's obvious now why it "doesn't work": `setDir` *returns a function* that needs be called with `dispatch` as argument. You are calling `setDir(...)` but are not doing anything with its return value (i.e. you are creating a function and are not calling it, so of course whatever code is inside the function is not executed).

Comment: yeah u had right. I forget to put `props.` before `setDir`. Thank you @FelixKling

Answer (score 0):

Hii, 
You should try to put it 
 `const newDirection = dir === "asc" ? "desc" : "asc";` 
 before the console.log or inside the return.

Comment: And why do you think would that solve the problem?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).